# UITextView auto-complete bubble location

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextview

I am confused regarding auto-complete bubble location while entering data in UITextView.

What i have observed is that depending upon its frame's origin , auto-complete bubble either comes on top or bottom. There is no fixed location, **provided scrollEnabled is set to NO**.

Here are the two links. Code is written in init()

http://www.flickr.com/photos/26021742@N00/6975525835/

```
UIView *view = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 150, 320, 41)] autorelease];
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
[self.view addSubview:view];
UITextView *growingTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 10, 200, 27)];
growingTextView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:13];
growingTextView.scrollEnabled = NO;
[view addSubview:growingTextView];
```

http://www.flickr.com/photos/26021742@N00/6975525727/

```
    UIView *view = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 320, 41)] autorelease];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    [self.view addSubview:view];
    UITextView *growingTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 10, 200, 27)];
    growingTextView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:13];
    growingTextView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    [view addSubview:growingTextView];
```

Can anyone explain this observed behavior ???

Answer (score 0):

I know that popovers and bubbles will always automatically adjust it's position for ease of use. It's already on Apple's code and in both images the bubble position makes sense.