# UITextView autocorrection type at top

Tags: iphone, uitextview

I have a `UITextView` and I need to show the autocorrection words suggested by apple at the top. Right now they are coming at the bottom and are hiding behind the editor.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing with the same problem that you are talking about. The truth is that we can't play with the position of auto-correction bubble.

Few things to try to see the behaviour of auto-correction bubble :
* try setScrollEnabled to NO, you will notice that it automatically comes at top.
* with the above setting (scrollEnabled= NO) ,  it depends upon the frame.origin.y , whether it comes on top, or bottom.

I have also posted a similar kind of question, to know the behaviour.
[UITextView auto-complete bubble location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9664341/uitextview-auto-complete-bubble-location)

What i am doing is to create multi-line textView similar to messages app. 
One simple implementation you can find as http://www.hanspinckaers.com/multi-line-uitextview-similar-to-sms ....

Otherwise, you can always write your own library, by testing all the behaviours.